# Laravel 5.2.29 Many to Many relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I am trying to implement many to many relationship using a pivot table. The name of my pivot table is "post_tag" and column names are "post_id" and "tag_id". The post and tag model classes look like below.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array(
        'title',
        'text',
        'active',
        'user_id'
    );

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'post_id');
    }

}
```

And the tag class is as below:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

The post_tag table looks like below:

```
post_id tag_id
1        1  
1        2  
2        1
```

I am trying the tags for the post using the following code:

```
$user = User::find(1);
    foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
        foreach ($post->tags as $tag) {
            print $tag->title;
            print "<br>";
        }
        print "<br>";
    }
```

But it throws an error:

QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`post_id` = 1 and `posts`.`post_id` is not null)

I think I missing something. Could anyone please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: your tags method on Post model must connect to App/Tag instead of App/Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are set wrong relationship in `tags()` method of Post Model. It should be `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');`

And in `posts()` method of Tag Model you should set return `$this->belongsToMany('App\Post');`

For more information you can see it in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Hi, I modified the method so that is looks like below:     
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
}
But it still does not work. It gives me this error now:
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tags` where `tags`.`post_id` = 1 and `tags`.`post_id` is not null)

Comment: You should use `belongsToMany` method see updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Follio. The suggested changes worked for me.